# Infinitude of Primes proof.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove the infinitude of prime numbers in a novel way.

Define a finite set of prime numbers

$$ P = \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_n\} $$

Define a set $S$ that includes numbers generated using the infinite power-product combinations of the primes in $P$

$$ S = \left\{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i^{a_i} : a_i \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $$

Define a *gap number* $G$ where $G \notin S$.

To summarize

> For any finite set of primes $P$ and its associated power-product set
> $S$, the existence of a gap number $G \notin S$ recursively yields a
> prime not in $P$, implying infinite primes.

**Example**

Let $P = \{2, 3\}$.

Define $S$ as a combination of powers and products of the primes 2 and 3

\begin{align*}
S &= \{2^1, 3^1, 2^2, 2^1 \times 3^1, 2^3, 3^2, 2^2 \times 3^1, 2^4, 2^1 \times 3^2, 2^3 \times 3^1, 3^3, \ldots\} \\
&= \{2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, \ldots\}
\end{align*}

Pick any *gap number*, say $G = 14$.

The prime factorization of $G$ is $2\times7$, so that $7$ is a new prime $\notin P$.

**Question**

Is there a way to show that *gap numbers* always exist?

**Idea**

Assuming $G$ exists, then either

1. $G$ is prime, so $G \notin P$.
2. $G$ is composite, then its prime factorization must contain at least one prime not in $P$.

Recursively adding a new prime factor of $G$ to $P$, shows there are infinite primes.

**UPDATE**

I'd like to combine all these ideas into a single succinct proof. So, as a variation of [Euclid's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid%27s_proof), is the following an accurate summary of the proof of Infinite Primes using Gap Numbers?

**Proof**

For a finite set of primes
$P = \{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n\}$,
define set $S = \left\{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i^{a_i} : a_i \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$. Since the growth rate of $S$ is $O(\log^n N)^\dagger$ and $N$ grows linearly, for large $N$, there exist *gap numbers* $ G \notin S$. Each $G$ must have a prime divisor $\notin P$. Thus, infinite primes exist. $\blacksquare$

$^\dagger$ Chaitin, G.

If there are more rigorous ways to express this proof or a reference to *Chaitin*, please feel free to leave an answer. Thanks!

Comment: The first approach is very similar to Euclid's idea. The second does not work. An elegant prime that there are infinite many primes based on pairwise coprime numbers is possible with the Fermat numbers. It can easily be proven that they are pairwise coprime and every such number has of course at least one prime factor.

Comment: That limit notation doesn't make much sense, $N$ is just $\infty$. It is true that if you take $N = p_1 p_2 \dots p_n$ then $\gcd(N, N+1) = 1$ but this is just Euclid's proof.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you think is "new" about this approach.  This is exactly how the usual proof (Euclid's) goes: given any finite set of primes, it explicitly constructs a "gap number" for it (or in fact something stronger, a number that is not even divisible by any of the primes in your set).  There are other ways you can prove the existence of "gap numbers" besides the specific construction used by Euclid but there's nothing novel about the framing you give.

Comment: You've observed that "there are infinitely many primes" is equivalent to "with only finitely many primes, we can't make every number". As Eric says, this is fairly obvious. The interesting part is proving that there really are numbers you can't make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to show that gap numbers always exist?

Yes, there are a couple of ways to do this. One is count the number of elements of $S$ less than or equal to some positive integer $N$ and show that as $N$ gets sufficiently large there are less than $N$ of them. In fact we have that if $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i} \le N$ then $a_i \le \log_{p_i} N$ which means that there are at most

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \lfloor \log_{p_i} N + 1 \rfloor$$

elements of $S$ less than or equal to $N$, and this grows like $O(\log^n N)$ which is eventually much slower than $N$. I have heard this argument attributed to Chaitin. He phrases it "information-theoretically" as follows: if there were finitely many primes, then the prime factorization would be an extremely efficient way to compress a positive integer, in fact so efficient it's impossible. This argument can be used to prove a very bad version of the prime number theorem, along the lines that there are must be at least $\frac{\log N}{\log \log N}$ primes $\le N$.

Another way to do this is to show that the sum

$$\sum_{s \in S} \frac{1}{s}$$

converges, while the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, which also implies that $S$ can't be all of $\mathbb{N}$. I have heard this argument attributed to Euler (in a slightly different form). You can show more precisely that the sum above is the finite [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p_i}}$$

whereas the harmonic series is, informally speaking, the infinite Euler product. This idea can be pushed a bit to show that the sum $\sum_i \frac{1}{p_i}$ of the reciprocals of the primes also diverges, which also shows that there are infinitely many primes (and this version of the argument is, I think, the one really due to Euler but I'm not sure).

> Assuming $G$ exists, then either
>
> 1. $G$ is prime, so $G \notin P$.
> 2. $G$ is composite, then its prime factorization must contain at least one prime not in $P$.

It's not necessary to break into cases like this. Whether $G$ is prime or composite, it's divisible by at least one prime not in $P$ either way, by definition. Alternatively you can argue that the smallest gap number is prime.

Comment: Awesome! Seeing as you've proven gap numbers always exist, am I correct to assume it's a valid approach towards proving the infinitude of primes? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy: yes, either of these gives you a valid proof.