# A Variant Proof of Euclid's Infinitude of Primes.

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers

I'd like to propose a variation on [Euclid's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem), that given only finitely many primes, we cannot generate every number.

*Disclaimer:* I occasionally dabble in maths so I'm pretty sure these methods below could be made more rigorous.

---

$\textbf{Lemma 1 (Existence of Gap Numbers)}$

Given a finite set of primes $P = \{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$  and a set
$S = \left\{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i^{a_i} : a_i \in \mathbb{N_0} \right\}$
for some sufficiently large positive integer $N$, there exist gap numbers $G$ such that $G \leq N$ and $G \notin S$.

$\textbf{Proof}$ (Based on Qiaochu Yuan's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782519/infinitude-of-primes-proof))

For each $p_i$, the exponent $a_i$ is bounded by $\log_{p_i} N$, ensuring that $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i} \leq N$. Therefore, there are at most
$\lfloor \log_{p_i} N + 1 \rfloor$
choices for each $a_i$. The total number of different values in $S$ that are $\leq N$ is
$\prod_{i=1}^n \lfloor \log_{p_i} N + 1 \rfloor$.
This count grows as $O(\log^n N)$, which, for large $N$, is slower than the linear growth of $N$ itself. Consequently, there will be values (gap numbers) in the range up to $N$ that are not in $S$. $\blacksquare$

---

$\textbf{Theorem (Infinitude of Primes)}$

There exist infinitely many prime numbers.

$\textbf{Proof}$

Let $P = \{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$ be a finite set of primes. By *Lemma 1*, there exists a gap number $G \notin S$. So there exists a prime $q$ such that $q | G$ and $q \notin P$, contradicting the finiteness of $P$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This variant would be much more difficult than any of the standard proofs (Euclid , harmonic series, Fermat numbers). Is there any motivation to establish such a complicated proof ?

Comment: It was a personal goal to create a variation of Euclids proof. Spent a day thinking about it and this idea popped up that given a small list of prime numbers, we can't make every natural number from every possible power-products combinations, so there are gap numbers that must have a prime factor not in the initial list of primes. It's obvious these gap numbers exist, but I lacked the mathematical knowledge to prove it. Luckily, Qiaochu showed two such methods, although there are other easier ways to prove the existence of "gap numbers". Once gap numbers exist, implies infinite primes exist.